# Связать таблицу rating с таблицами users и comments

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Есть три таблицы (в скобках поля):

- `users (id, username, password, created)`
- `rating (id, username, comment)`
- `comments(id, comment, username, created)`

Как мне лучше связать таблицу `rating` с таблицами `users` и `comments`, чтобы у каждого комментария был свой рейтинг, а у каждого юзера тоже свой рейтинг, примерно как на этом сервисе.

Как можно изначально полю рейтинга задать по умолчанию 0, а потом либо увеличивать на 1, либо уменьшать на -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше добавить поле рейтинг в каждую из таблиц, юзера и коммента.

Comment: Спасибо, а как можно изначально полю рейтинга задать по-умолчанию 0, а потом либо увеличивать на 1, либо уменьшать на -1?

Comment: ну смотря на чем ты пишешь..., 0 можно задать по деволту, а рейтинг должен изменятся динамически с помощью того, кто работает с этой таблицей

Comment: Пишу на PHP + MySQL. Хочу сделать так, чтобы при увеличении рейтинга комментария на 1, рейтинг пользователя увеличивался на 5 - одновременно!